# How to check if view was already loaded? (InflateException: Duplicate id)

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I'm building an android app in which I use one Activity from which I can load several fragments. So I start with the FragmentA, and from that I load Fragment B as follows:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, detailsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This works fine. When I press the backbutton, it also goes back to FragmentA perfectly well. The problem is that when I click on the button to go to FragmentB *again* I get an InflateException (`Duplicate id 0x7f08007a, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.ourcomp.fragment.DetailsFragment`) on this line:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, null);
}
```

I think I need to check whether it was inflated already, but I don't really know how. Does anybody know how I can check wether the view was already inflated so that I can prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

After checking [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#UI) again, I found:

*The ViewGroup to be the parent of the inflated layout. Passing the container is important in order for the system to apply layout parameters to the root view of the inflated layout, specified by the parent view in which it's going.*

So try to replace

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, null);
```

with

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container);
```